# I'm trying to clear the cache of my app when it closes (onDestroy)

Tags: android, caching, android-studio

I tried finding a answer, but i came up with nothing. i can't seem to find a way to clear the cache of the app when it closes.

```
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    try {
        trimCache(this);
         Toast.makeText(this,"onDestroy " ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
public static void trimCache(Context context) {
    try {
        File dir = context.getCacheDir();
        if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
            deleteDir(dir);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}

public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
    if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
            if (!success) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    // The directory is now empty so delete it
    return dir.delete();
}
```

this what i came acrros, but somehow to cache is still here... FYI i'm new on android

Comment: Have you run it under a debugger?  What's failing?

Comment: Well the cache is simply not going away :/, tired a bunch of stuff

Comment: Is an exception being thrown?  Have you verified delete is being called?  Is it returning true or false?  Is it possibly timing out (onDestroy has a limited time to run before a watchdog is tripped).  Is onDelete even being called, since there's no garuntee that it will be?